# AVR gcrt1.S weird call

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

So basically i have decompiled unoptimized simple program and saw that it runs through gcrt1.S, and i dived in to assembly language and tried to understand what exactly it does. here is my code and my assumption of what it does

```
00000034  CLR R1        Clear Register 
00000035  OUT 0x3F,R1       Out to I/O location 
00000036  SER R28       Set Register        
00000037  LDI R29,0x08      Load immediate      
00000038  OUT 0x3E,R29      Out to I/O location 
00000039  OUT 0x3D,R28      Out to I/O location 
0000003A  CALL 0x00000040       Call subroutine 
0000003C  JMP 0x00000050        Jump 
0000003E  JMP 0x00000000        Jump 


Clear R1
Clear stratus register
Set R28 1111 1111

Here is where my questions start:
Load R29 from 0x08 (PORTC ?)
OUT to SPH <-R29
OUT to SPL <-R28
Call Main
```

The confuision that i have is why it loads byte from PORTC register, since the default would be 0x00 anyway

Microcontroller is atmega328p  [link to a datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> Load R29 from 0x08 (PORTC ?)

The instruction is `LDI R29,0x08` which loads 8 into R29.  LDI is "load immediate to register"; it does not read from memory, see section "31. Instruction Set Summary" in the ATmega328 manual you are using.  The code is initializing the frame pointer `Y` from symbol `__stack`, see startup code in [gcrt1.S](http://svn.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/avr-libc/trunk/avr-libc/crt1/gcrt1.S?revision=2519&view=markup#l220).